# php, wordpress add line break with in two echo statements

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

```
<?php if (is_page_template()) { 
  echo get_page_template_slug(); 
  echo get_page_template() ;
?>
```

is there any way to print this two echo statements in different line with out closing php and use html to line break

in plane php

```
<?php if ( 1 ==1 ) {
  echo 'first line';
  echo 'second line';
}
```

the two echo values might `not be string` in all cases

---

how to add line break after an echo statement, so that the next statement prints in new line

Comment: Add ``echo '<br />';`` or ``echo '\n\n';`` in between the two lines?

Comment: the two echo values might `not be string` in all cases

Comment: So what? You can concatenate them anyway. The arguments of [``echo()``](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) are always ``string``.

Comment: thats already added in question, but some users did't notice that ,  any how please delete comments which are not related to question , i too will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if (is_page_template()) { 
  echo get_page_template_slug() . '</br>'; 
  echo get_page_template();
?>
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

You can just add html in the echo:

```
echo "my line <br />";
echo "second line";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this. Use concatenation and use HTML `</br>` tag. Or you can use `'\n'` for line break.

```
<?php if ( 1 ==1 ) {
  echo 'first line'.'<br>'.'second line';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of ways doing this - the way i like it when i have few php values is like this.

```
<?php if ( 1 ==1 ) : ?>
<!-- normal html here -->
  <div>
    <p class="whatever"><?php echo 'first line'; ?></p>
    <p class="whatever2"><?php echo 'second line'; ?></p>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this way, you can just write whatever HTML you like

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [**nl2br()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) php function which inserts line breaks where newlines (\n) occur in the string:

```
<?php
  echo nl2br("One line.\nAnother line.");
?>
```

**Output :**

One line.

Another line.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

echo "line1 
";
echo "Line2";

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution :

```
<?php
    echo "First line\n";
    echo "Second Line";
```

If you change double quotes with single quote it will not work.
What you can do is :

```
<?php
    echo 'First Line' . "\n";
    echo 'Second line';
```