# Echo text file line by line HTML-PHP

Tags: php, html

I have searched the site but none of the answers i found has worked so far so i'm seeking additional help.

I want to print the lines from a text file line by line (one under the other) but i do not wish to use iframe here is my code so far:

HTML-PHP

```
<td>
<?php                                       
$handle = fopen("textfilelocation/$text.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
echo $line;
}                                       
fclose($handle);
} 
else {
echo "Error accessing Tracking Data";
} 
?>
</td>
```

Text file

```
Hello,World 
March 3, 2018, 3:00am
Enjoy, life
```

Ouput

`Hello,World March 3, 2018, 3:00am Enjoy, life`

What i want is

```
Hello,World 
March 3, 2018, 3:00am
Enjoy, life
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve and display text exactly how it is typed and submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045667/preserve-and-display-text-exactly-how-it-is-typed-and-submitted)

Comment: put it in a pre tag, or add <br> after it.

Comment: So you need to add a html line break? `<br>`? `echo $line . "<br>\n";`

Comment: Use `echo nl2br($line)`?

Comment: Change echo $line; to echo $line .'<br>';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php, wordpress add line break with in two echo statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458297/php-wordpress-add-line-break-with-in-two-echo-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reading the file a line at a time because you think you need to do that to display each line on a new line in the browser, it isn't necessary. You just need to convert the line breaks to `<br>` tags.

```
<td>
    <?= nl2br(file_get_contents('example.txt')) ?>
</td>
```

Otherwise, if you are doing something else to `$line` before you output it, just append a `<br>`.

```
echo "$line<br>";
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much that works perfectly! i upvoted you but its not showing, not sure how to build my rep yet

Comment: @Time no worries. Re: rep, you might want to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow